# How do I fix an import error for the SQLite Studio Android-Plugin that does exist?

Tags: android, plugins, sqlitestudio

**My Problem**: I'm receiving the flowing error when trying to launch my Android application with the SQLiteStudioRemote plugin (jar file). Below is a copy of the error and an image the shows the jar is properly included as an external jar and that the import acknowledges its existence.

> error: package pl.com.salsoft.sqlitestudioremote does not exist
>   import pl.com.salsoft.sqlitestudioremote.SQLiteStudioService;

[image: Import statement and external jar]

**What I have tried**: I followed the SQLite Studio links for the instructions and video provided through the SQLite Studio Help > User Manual. I searched for this specific error but nothing turned up specific to this error. I'm using the SQLite 3 version and using the Intellij IDEA for development.

[Video Instruction through Help link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eFKLGsfpwNc)

[Instructions online through Help link](https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio/wiki/DbAndroid)

**What I'm trying to do**: I'm trying to use the SQLite Studio plugin for connecting to an Android SQLite database in an Android application I'm developing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get passed this issue, but the actual issue was never resolved. However, I didn't want to leave an open question.

I opened my SQLite DB in the Android app Assets folder through SQLiteStudio directly. I was never able to get the SQLiteStudioRemote.jar to work. At the time of this post, I reached out to Salsoft and they were not sure why SQLiteStudioRemote would not work with Intellij IDEA as they use Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Why You don't use the Database Navigator. In AndroidStudio -> Settings -> plugins..and search for database navigator.

I prefer SQL Browser for SQLight (You can find it [here](https://sqlitebrowser.org/))